# Mapinfo Vertical Mapper interpolation VS QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, vertical-mapper

I am currently trying to fade out the use of MapInfo and only use QGIS (or Global Mapper) however I find that I am still needing to use Vertical Mapper for interpolations. We are using MapInfo V12 and QGIS V2.8. Below are images of Vertical Mapper grid interpolation using Nearest Neighbour and QGIS grid interpolation using nearest neighbour. Vertical Mapper's output is much more smooth and allows for smooth contour lines to be created. I guess what I'm asking is can QGIS produce these results?

[image: MapInfo]

[image]

Comment: The vertical mapper output looks odd.. It's not a nearest neighbor interpolation at all. Try changing the algorithm in the QGIS interpolator and you'll get similar results

Comment: It might look different because I didn't select 'ignore zeros'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a different 'natural neighbor' interpolation in the Processing Toolbox (rather than the Raster drop down menu) that gave a much better output

I used a cell size of 1 and left the rest as defult:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the **Resize** setting which determines the amount of pixels that would be produced. This *should* improve the resolution of your raster, and ergo, increase the smoothness.

[image: Grid interpolation settings]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have re-sized the image, and this does increase the resolution, however it still remains very 'box-like' and there is no smooth interpolation between elevations. I have up-dated the image above to reflect this.